# Add or modify list values

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a model class named `ValueModelClass` where I am storing all the values of it to a `List<ValueModelClass>`. Ideally if 3 values of incoming values match in one of `ValueModelClass` data in List, I am modifying the value of it within the list to avoid any duplicates.

Using the below code to perform the action. But in this case when the `ValueModelClass` value is modified in the list, when it comes out of the `foreach` loop the data is again added to the `List`. I dint want to add to the list if the value has been modified under `foreach` loop. Please suggest how can I do this?

```
List<ValueModelClass> listValues = new List<ValueModelClass>();
string[] data = line.Split(',');

foreach (var listValue in listValues.ToArray())
{
    if (listValue.name == data[4] && listValue.description == data[3] && listValue.rule == data[2])
    {
        var i = listValues.FindIndex(x => x.hostName.Equals(listValue.name));
        listValues[i].destinationValue.Add(data[0]);
        listValues[i].sourceKey.Add(data[1]);
    }
}

listValues.Add(ValueModelClass);
```

Adding my sample code for understanding: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UHqBH

I would need the output something as below:

```
{"destinationValue":["https://test.com","https://test2.com","https://test3.com","https://test3.com"],"sourceKey":["/test","/test2","/test3","/test3"],"rule":"rulename1","name":"name1","description":" description1"}
{"destinationValue":["https://test1.com"],"sourceKey":["/test1"],"rule":"rulename2","name":"name2","description":" description2"}
```

But the output I get is,

```
{"destinationValue":["https://test.com","https://test2.com","https://test3.com","https://test3.com"],"sourceKey":["/test","/test2","/test3","/test3"],"rule":"rulename1","name":"name1","description":" description1"}
{"destinationValue":["https://test1.com"],"sourceKey":["/test1"],"rule":"rulename2","name":"name2","description":" description2"}
{"destinationValue":["https://test2.com"],"sourceKey":["/test2"],"rule":"rulename1","name":"name1","description":" description1"}
{"destinationValue":["https://test3.com"],"sourceKey":["/test3"],"rule":"rulename1","name":"name1","description":" description1"}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the source code for `ValueModelClass`.

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray` since you're not actually mutating the list in the loop.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble understanding what you actually want

Comment: @mjwills: Please refer the sample at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UHqBH

Comment: @TheGeneral: Please refer the sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UHqBH

Comment: @juharr I had to add it since I was not able to modify the list if some values match.

Comment: Just move your code around some so the logic matches what you want. In pseudo-code: `if (an existing item matches this item) { modify the existing item } else { create a new item, populate it's properties, and add it to the list }` This way you only add an item if you're creating a new one, and you only create a new one if you're not modifying an existing one.

Comment: @Dhillli4u Your current code does not modify the list in the `foreach` loop.  It modifies items in the list.  Modifying the list would be removing or adding items.  If that `Add` was in the loop then yes you would need the `ToArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rufus L suggested in a comment you need to revisit your logic a bit. At the moment you are going through the whole collection of `listValues` and verify if all the items match your duplicate criteria. If any of the values are different - you are adding a new entry.

But you need to do the opposite - if any of the values match - do not add new one! Here is the potential fix:

```
    foreach (var line in dataline)
    {
       string[] data = line.Split(',');
       ValueModelClass valueModelClass = new ValueModelClass()
       {
           destinationValue = new List<string> { data[0] },
           sourceKey = new List<string> { data[1] },
           rule = data[2],
           description = data[3],
           name = data[4]
       };

       if (listValues.Any(x => x.name == data[4] && x.description == data[3] && x.rule == data[2]))
       {               
           var i = listValues.FindIndex(x => x.name.Equals(valueModelClass.name));
           listValues[i].destinationValue.Add(data[0]);
           listValues[i].sourceKey.Add(data[1]);
       }
       else
       {
           listValues.Add(valueModelClass);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I was using the LINQ within the foreach loop which was causing the issue. Trying with your suggestion worked for me.